# How to ignore hard space (~) in siunitx number parsing

Tags: siunitx

I used to format number grouping with a protected space (`~`). Now I'm switching to siunitx's `\num`. According to the package documentation ...

> The formatter removes ‘hard’ spaces (`\,` and `~`)

but when I surround my numbers with `\num` it produces the following error output

```
! siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number"
! Invalid token '\protect ' in numerical input.

l.5 \num{60~000}

| Numbers can only contain tokens defined using the 'input-...' options:
| the token '\protect ' is not set up as a valid part of a number.
```

I tried to include `\protect` to the `input-ignore` option but it just changes the invalid token in the error message to `\unhbox` and `\voidb`.

Here is a MWE (Miktex v2.9 and siunitx v2.5s):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{input-ignore={\protect }}
\begin{document}
\num{60~000}
\end{document}
```

Of course, one could just remove the tilde character in each number but how would I include it into the ignored input tokens? Do I misinterpret the package documentation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's a mistake in the documentation: currently the standard settings ignore `\,` but not `~`. I'll fix that in a maintenance release: for the moment use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-ignore=~,
  input-protect-tokens = ~\approx\dots\ge\geq\gg\le\leq\ll\mp\pi\pm\sim}
\begin{document}
\num{60\,000}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Logged as https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/256 and likely to be actioned by the weekend. I've got a few minor issues to address, one of which means I'll have to bump the version to 2.6. Bother me if CTAN is not updated by Monday!

Comment: It's amazing to have such people one the site!

Comment: A proper fix has now gone to CTAN: should be with users of TeX Live/MiKTeX within a few days.

Comment: @JosephWright updated my library today. Works like a charm and makes the workaround unnecessary :)